# Can I set the post_type query_var as a link is clicked?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have 2 custom post types that use some of the same taxonomies. I would like to be able to show all entries in the taxonomy ( no problem here) and then just each of the post types. But I would like to do it without creating a mess of custom pages using a template.

Can I set up a function to change the post_type query_var when the link is clicked? SO if I had a set of navigation links in my left sidebar, the set to 'designer' post type would set the post_type query_var to 'designer'. The same would need to happen for the 'boutique' post type navigation links.

I think I may need to use some javascript but am unsure. Is this possible? I'm not an expert by an means but I believe this MIGHT be possible,

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` filter hook to set the post type passed by the user:

paste this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
function user_set_type( $query ) {
    //only on your taxonomy page
    if ( $query->is_tax('YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY') ) {

        //and only if the guesst has selected a type
        if (isset($_GET['UTYPE']) && !empty($_GET['UTYPE'])){
            $query->set( 'post_type', $_GET['UTYPE'] );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'user_set_type' );
```

Change `YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY` to the name of your taxonomy, then on your taxonomy page  or widgets all  you need to do is create links with the post_type as parameters in them eg:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink() . '?UTYPE=designer"; ?>">Designers</a> - <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() . '?UTYPE=boutique" ?>">Boutiques</a>
```

Comment: Thanx! That worked perfectly, wasn't aware of pre_get_posts method.